# No page break after section

Tags: packages, page-breaking, section-titles

I uploaded a template, with these packages. But I have a limited amount of pages, and now after I make a new section using `\section{}`, The section starts on a new page. How do I make sure they are on the same page?

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
   \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}                    
   \usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}               
   \usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{subcaption}  
\usepackage{sectsty}  
   \usepackage{apacite}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{titling}       
   \usepackage{blindtext}             
   \usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}               
   \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}  
\usepackage{xcolor}      
   \definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.4, 0.0}

\begin{document}

\section{Aaaaa}
zzzz
\section{Aaaaa}
zzzz
\section{Aaaaa}
zzzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: your title asks about `\caption` and the text of your question describes `\section` and the code you posted does not use either?  caption sare normally in a box liek a figure that can not break, and latex does not break after a section heading so it is hard to understand your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, In my text i use \section{} and I want to make different sections, but they start on a new page and i want them on the same page. But i don't know which package influences that

Comment: It is impossible to say anything since you have posted no example, please edit your example so it shows your problem. Also perhaps change your title not to mention captions if the question is not about `\caption` ?

Comment: I added some `\section` to the example preamble that you posted, but it makes three section headings on one page. Please fix the example so that it shows the problem, which is presumably due to code you have not shown.

Comment: LaTeX won't have the section title at the bottom of the page and then start the section text at the top of the next page.  Is that what you're wanting to happen?